# Change Menu after Logging In

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu, login, acl, user-groups

I have a test website currently using the Helix3 Quickstart - http://helix3.financialadvisersaustralia.com.au/

I have created a new User Group and a New Menu assigned to the new User Group. When I login, I want the Main Menu to disappear completely and the new Menu appear with a different set of options.

I am ok with hiding menu items in the existing Main Menu as I have setup the Login/Logout scenario using Quick Logout plugin but I am struggling to work out how I can change the Menu completely depending on which User Group logs in.

At present, I am trying to get 1 New User Group but I may eventually have more than a dozen.

I have tried finding a solution online but everything is just about the "login" changing to "logout".

Answer (score 1):

You will need **ACL levels** according to your **user groups**. Then create the corresponding content/menus/modules etc considering your groups/viewing levels and assign each content item to that access viewing level.

However, if you are going to have too many different groups with different access levels, then it might be better to use a Membership extension that can control what members group has access to each content item.